# How to connect to remote SFTP server from OpenShift .NET Core POD using SSH.NET

Tags: .net-core, openshift, sftp, ssh.net

I have a .NET Core 2.2 service running in OpenShift. My service uses [SSH.NET](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET) to connect to my remote SFTP Server running outside the OpenShift cloud. The SFTP server is configured to provide only SFTP on port 22.

According to [SSH.NET](https://github.com/sshnet/SSH.NET), the code to connect to an SFTP server is:

```
var connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo("10.1.2.3",
                                        "guest",
                                        new PasswordAuthenticationMethod("guest", "pwd"),
                                        new PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod("rsa.key"));
using (var client = new SftpClient(connectionInfo))
{
    client.Connect();
}
```

**This code works fine when used inside my intranet.**

To access a remote resource in OpenShift I have created an egress router that provides a fix IP. All firewalls have been configured to allow accees from OpenShift to my SFTP Server.

**My question:**

What value shall I use for first parameter in the ConnectionInfo class above? The IP address "10.1.2.3" of my remote server will not work from inside OpenShift because outbound traffic must strictly go through the egress router service.

**Note:**
I can already access the remote server via HTTPS using an http client access from my POD using URL like this: https://x-myservice-egress.y-myproject-infra-test:4433.

Comment: Can you connect to your SFTP server using any standalone SFTP client running on the same machine as your .NET code?

Comment: Not possible to do that! we use a private/on-premise RedHed cloud, I don't have permissions to run/install any tools there

Comment: Well, we first need to know,  if your even have a network connectivity. Until you prove that, you do not have a programming question.

Comment: I have a network connectivity as state in the "Note" question. The network and firewalls are all setup and the end to end connectivity works fine for https.

The question is an SSH.NET and OpenShift question.

Comment: HTTP connectivity is not relevant for SSH.

Comment: Why is this counted down!!!! at least leave a comment for the reason!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ConenctionInfo class I must provide the egress router name and a mapping port, e.g. projectName-egress-xyz:2201. The 2201 is a mapping ID not a physical port, it maps to my real SFTP server host machine IP and port 22.

The code below worked!

```
var connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo("projectName-egress-xyz:2201",
                                        "guest",
                                        new PasswordAuthenticationMethod("guest", "pwd"),
                                        new PrivateKeyAuthenticationMethod("rsa.key"));
using (var client = new SftpClient(connectionInfo))
{
    client.Connect();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace it with egress router name and source port mapped to destination port that you defined in your egress configuration.

Ex egress-xyz:source-port